# java observer GUI not updating

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, observable

I managed to send an update to my observer (textarea)
when I logged `textarea.getText()` the result is my updated message.
but the GUI is not updating (still blank). What is the problem?

my observer

```
public void update(Observable o, Object data){

    jTextArea2.setText((String)data);

}
```

my observable

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2736805471773039923L;
    final ObjectObservable observable;
    public Login()
    {

        observable = new ObjectObservable();
        JFrame calender = new Kalender();
        observable.addObserver((Observer) calender);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
    {                                         
            observable.changeData(jTextField1.getText());
    }   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
          java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Login().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is right there --> .......... (I show you more, if you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then updated your question accordingly).

Comment: Can't help you without your code, trimmed down to a [mcve].

Comment: edited... thanks for your help.